# How can I set a filter for mysql column with statement procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this problem on setting a BETWEEN clause for dates.
See my code here:

First set of code: JS file passing parameters to PHP handler file using AJAX

```
$('#load_data').click(function () {

        let data = {
            'action': 'load_export',
            'start_date': '2021-07-01', //sample start date
            'end_date': '2021-07-03' //sample end_date
        }

        data = $.param(data);

        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
             url: 'handler.php',
            success: (data) => { console.log(data) },
            error: (data) => { console.log(data) }
        });

    });
```

Second set of code: From the AJAX request above, PHP handler file parse the data and sent to an OOP PHP file for query.

```
<?php

if(ajaxRequest()){
  if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])){
     
     $action = $_POST['action'];
     
     switch($action){
          case "load_export"    : load_export(); break;
     }

  }
}

function ajaxRequest(){ return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
&& strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';}

function load_export(){

    require_once('oop.php');
    $return = $_POST;
    $result = '';
    $array_fields = array('*');
    //this variable $table holds the view from database and 
    //its query is the SQL one showed below
    $table = 'vw_test';
    $joins = '';
    $sql_where = "";
    $sql_order = '';
    $sql_limit = '';
    $result = MYCLASS::getInstance()->select_query(
       $array_fields,
       $table,
       $joins,
       $sql_where,
       $sql_order,
       $sql_limit
   );
   
   $ctr = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $return['emp_id'][$ctr] = $row['emp_id'];
     // should return rows
        $ctr++;
    }
        
        $return['ctr']    = $ctr;
        echo json_encode($return);

    }

?>
```

Third set of code: This is the OOP that queries to mysql database and returns the result back to the handler who passes the results back to js ajax request:

```
public function select_query($array_fields,$table,$joins,$sql_where,$sql_order,$sql_limit){
        $query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS " . implode(", ", $array_fields) 
. " FROM {$table} {$joins} {$sql_where} {$sql_order} {$sql_limit};";
        return $this->query($query);
    }
```

This is the code for the making the pivot record (vw_test):

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
         CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN assigned_date = ''', assigned_date,
                ''' THEN (manhour) END) `', assigned_date, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM tbl_attendance;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT emp_id, ', @sql, ' FROM tbl_attendance GROUP BY emp_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This is the actual result from the query above:
[image: Query List]

Now the question is how can I set something to filter the dates(header) displayed. Something like...

```
SELECT emp_id FROM tbl_attendance WHERE assigned_date BETWEEN param1 AND param2
```

I really appreciate any sort of idea or correction. Thanks!

Comment: does the code you show know what the parameters are?  it's not clear why you can't just add the WHERE...BETWEEN in your `SET @SQL = CONCAT...`

Comment: you tagged it php; can you show the php code that calls/runs the sql code you show?

Comment: Sorry, I already updated the information. Hope to get something. Thanks in advance